# Create a resizable table grid, resizing using mouse, inside a content editable using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, resizable

I want to create a regular resizable table grid inside a content editable. The table should be resizable using the mouse, preferebly resizable in both the x-axis and y-axis but this question is more directed towards resizing in the x-axis. I have the following code

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
<!--- <script src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<title>Resizable table hobby testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div contenteditable="true" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
<button onclick="insert_table(5, 5);>insert table</button>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

tr, td {
    width: 60px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

javascript.js

```
var th_element;
var startOffset;

function insert_table(rows, cols) { // inserts a table into the div
    // gets the selected text inside the content editable div and deletes it
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
    // Create a table element
    var ins_table = document.createElement("table");
    // set unique id, useful for getting the element later
    ins_table.setAttribute("id", "table"); // maybe change to ins_table.id = "table";? (note to self)
    // Create the format of rows and columns for the table
    for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        ins_table.innerHTML += "<tr></tr>";
        ins_table.childNodes[r].innerHTML = "<tr>" + '<td style="min-width: 30px;"> </td>'.repeat(cols) + "</tr>";
    }

    // general css styling
    ins_table.style.width = "200px";
    ins_table.style.float = "left";

    // insert table into cursor position
    range.insertNode(ins_table);

    // get the table by finding its id
    var the_table = document.getElementById('table');

    // get the first row, in order to add a div there that acts as a resize bar grab thingy
    var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
    var cols = row.childNodes; // the cols is all the child nodes of the first row

    for(var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) { // iterate through all cols and insert the resize grab thingt
        var div = create_div(the_table.offsetHeight); // create a div for the selected cell with the height of the table
        cols[i].appendChild(div); // append that div to the cell
        cols[i].style.position = "relative"; // change position
        cols[i].style.overflow = "visible"; // needs to be set as visible to actually be used on the other rows. Without this it only works with the first row
        add_listener(div, cols[i]); // add a listener
    }
}

function create_div(height){ // create the div the user grabs onto
    var div = document.createElement('div'); // create the resize div to grab onto later
    // general styling
    div.style.top = 0;
    div.style.right = 0;
    div.style.width = '5px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
    div.style.userSelect = 'none';
    div.style.height = height + 'px';
    div.className = 'columnSelector';
    div.style.border = "none";
    return div; // return the created div, to be inserted into the cell above
}

function add_listener(div, col) {
    div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
        th_element = col;
        startOffset = col.offsetWidth - event.pageX;
    });

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        if(th_element) {
            th_element.style.width = startOffset + event.pageX + 'px';
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        th_element = undefined;
    });
}
```

I have tried the code from [brainbell](https://www.brainbell.com/javascript/making-resizable-table-js.html) but it does not span over multiple cells, nor does it work for me without tweaking the variable calls (e.g. brainbell uses parentElement instead of parentNode, which breaks for me). Dragging a div (the thing you grab onto to resize the table) too far right or left causes werid behaviour with other cells getting resized whilst not being ment to. Among other things.

The code I have taken inspiration from is [Resizing tables in vanilla JavaScript without affecting positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48883679/resizing-tables-in-vanilla-javascript-without-affecting-positioning) but as you can see it breaks in multiple ways (1) when for example I drag the second div grab resize element back and forth, the first div shakes. (2) resizing using the third or fourth div causes weird resizes. (3) I am inside a content editable, making the text inside the table selected, I think it is because the resizing of the tables does not happen fast enough, thus the mouse is "dragged over" the text in the next, previous, etc cell despite that not being mean to happen (disabling highlighting in a contenteditable during resizing is not possible, I tried doing that via CSS). Among other things.

I am doing a minimal, "classic", vanilla javascript style coding hobby here thus I am not going to use jQuery. Does anybody know how to either (1) fix my code a bit or (2) how to create a resizble table grid (using vanilla JS and the mouse to resize) with editable content inside the cells please post a comment or an answer! Thanks!

[Here](https://codepen.io/your_daddy/pen/povaVrK) is also a codepen to SOMEWHAT illustrate my issue, because for some reason the codepen is less broken than mine that I have running on a httpd server, not sure why mine is more broken (or slow?)

Comment: I tried putting this code into an executable code snippet but it was throwing too many errors to even get into the functionality bugs you talk about in the question. Can you [edit] the example code with a functional example or share a working codepen link? It's hard to help when this example code is throwing multiple errors.

Comment: @tshimkus [here is a codepen example](https://codepen.io/your_daddy/pen/povaVrK)